# Using inbuilt EffectsFactory on images

Tags: android

I am trying to use [Effects Factory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html) on images already in phone.  I have surfed net & still am not able to learn how to do that. It would be great if some code snippet is provided explaining how to use. Some links to tutorials are also appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out [HERE](http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/samples/android-16/HelloEffects/src/com/example/android/mediafx/HelloEffects.java) which shows the use of Effect Factory class.